# Get scroll height and set as top to an absolute positioned element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to show one image in light box.

I had given postion:fixed earlier. But when the image height is bigger than the screen height, it leads to problem.

**Problem is:**

Now I need to use absoulte concept. But problem here is, if i give a static "top" value in CSS, lightbox image will be shown at the top of the page, when a user clicks a link which is at bottom of the page.

**TO DO:**

I need to set scrolled height of the page as top: value of the lightbox imageimage . I tried scrollTop(). But didn't get.

**How to do that?**

Can you guys please tell me?

**Edit:**
Here is my concept: http://jsfiddle.net/velmurugansp/F7z4f/1/

```
<div stle="position:relative">
<div style="height:1000px">
Top Contents
</div>
<img src="http://ftape.com/model/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Caroline-Corinth-Models1-The-Model-Wall_4.jpg" width="630" height="630" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:-50%; margin-left:315px;display:block" id="img" />
</div>

<script>
scrollHeight=document.scrollTop();
$("#img").css("top",scrollHeight);
</script>
```

I need to give top:1000px; to "#img". Cos the height of previous element's height is 1000px;

Comment: That's the place where I got struck.
I need to know the rite way to get height of scrolled part of the page.
Hope you can get my point now, @Sano.

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks a lot @Stano.
If you put your's as an answer, i ll make it "accepted answer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a top position for the image can be used something like this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrollHeight = $(window).scrollTop();
        var img = $('#img');
        if (scrollHeight < $(document).height()-img.height()-20) {
            img.css("top", scrollHeight);
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F7z4f/3/)

Comment: Tx @Stano. The solution for which I was waiting for :P

Answer (score 0):

Yoy need to get scrollTop() of body or html element, not other element.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not change the height of your image using CSS? It might prevent the necessity for all the jQuery.

Comment: nope. As per client's expectations, image height shouldn't changes. its something around 600x600. For smaller screen monitors, we can't see the full size of the image. So he tell the image can be scrollable.